# Subsequent Socket connections to a web page take different times

Tags: java, sockets, http, caching, server

I've been asking a few questions lately, hopefully this will be the last (at least I answered one of them!)

I have the following straight forward code, connecting to a webpage via sockets (the parameters here are the IP address of the site buzzfeed.com):

```
Socket s = new Socket("23.34.229.118", 80);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
writer.println("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.buzzfeed.com\r\n");

String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // just read, do nothing. When printed, it print the correct data.
}

s.close();
```

This code works and prints the HTML source of buzzfeed.com. However, the first invokation of this program (I'm just starting the program over and over), always takes around twice or three times as much times as subsequent invokations, occurring within a very small time. For example:

- First invokation - 1500 milliseconds).
- Seconds invokation (immediately after) - 600 milliseconds.
- This invokation (immediately after the second) - 400 milliseconds.

Then, if I wait ~20 seconds, we go back to the "first invokation", and the connection takes around 1500 milliseconds again.

I think this is clearly a case of something being cached - either on my end, or the server's end. So, I've added these lines to my code:

```
// don't keep connections alive.
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

// do not cache dns.
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "0");
```

But it didn't work. Am I missing some property or explanation here? Some other "setProperty" which I can use to make the times uniform? Better yet, if this is a caching problem, how can I take care of this caching? And what is being cached anyways? I am connecting directly to an IP address...

If this is a known server behavior I would also like to know. Note that this doesn't always happen, for example, connecting to stackoverflow (104.16.33.249) generates varied response times (even though in this case it also seems subsequent responses are a bit faster). Is it related to static vs. dynamic pages? I'm a little confused and would welcome any answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - First invokation - 1500 milliseconds).
> - Seconds invokation (immediately after) - 600 milliseconds.
> - This invokation (immediately after the second) - 400 milliseconds.
>
> Then, if I wait ~20 seconds, we go back to the "first invokation", and
>   the connection takes around 1500 milliseconds again.

You could start by looking at the **HTTP-headers** from within a browser (<kbd>F12</kbd> / Network) or by using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's really happening with, for example, `Keep-Alive-` and `Cache-headers`, and the different timings.

For example, these are the headers returned by www.buzzfeed.com:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html
X-BuzzFeed: webdr05
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-BuzzFeed-Debug: /index (bucket testing)
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=29
Date: Sat, 26 Dec 2015 14:37:35 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive, Transfer-Encoding
```

See `Cache-Control: max-age=29` for example.

> If this is a known server behavior I would also like to know.

However, the difference in timing could also be caused by the **caching on the webserver**. A page, or parts thereof (the server uses `chunked mode` for this response: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), could be temporarily **cached server-side** until that part needs to be updated. This would then cause new queries to the database (which might take the most time), generation of the html, compressing the data and writing it to the servercache again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I did not know all of these HTTP headers and they make a lot of sense. I will test them in my code. Many thanks again!